# Examples of a working ITestCaseProvider implementation for NUnit?

Tags: nunit, nunit-addins

Does anyone have any working examples of an ITestCaseProvider?

The samples I've come across, don't get picked up by the any test runnings - GUI, Console or Resharper (I've put the assembly in all the right places).

I've added Debugger.Break to them all, in an attempt to force the debugger to kick in, but nothing so far.

I guess I'm after a step-by-step guide, if anyone either has one, or as come across one.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: What exactly do you need. Most likely it will not work with Resharper (at least until v6.1). It does not seem to load the addings correctly. However on NUnit console and GUI it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got my ITestCase provider working from [this blog here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/testing-times-ahead-extending-nunit/) and dropping my assembly here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\addins

Unfortunately it only works within the nunit GUI. ReSharper (v8.2) persists to be a pain by not loading it even though I also put my assembly here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\addins

Would love to see a test framework with much easier extension points and easy ReSharper integrations.